# Como generar un marcador personalizado en google maps con una circunferencia de fondo y una imagen en el centro de esta?

Tags: flutter

He utilizado el siguiente codigo para generar un marcador en cualquier posicion del mapa:

```
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> createCustomMarkerBitmapWithNameAndImage(
      String imagePath, Size size, String name) async {

    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);

    Rect rect = const Rect.fromLTWH(
      0,
      0,
      150,
      150,
    );

    final blackPaintCircle = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = AppTheme.dullGold
      ..maskFilter = const MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, 10.0)
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    final blackPaintCircle2 = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = AppTheme.dullGold;

    const double radiusCircle = 60;

    const double offset = 50;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width/2 - offset, size.height/2 - offset), radiusCircle, blackPaintCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width/2 - offset, size.height/2 - offset), radiusCircle, blackPaintCircle2);

    ui.Image image = await getUiImage(imagePath, size.height.toInt(), size.width.toInt());
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, image: image, rect: rect, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
    

    ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    
    final imageF = await picture.toImage(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt());
    final byteData = await imageF.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

Este metodo es llamado a partir del siguiente:

```
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> getMarkerIcon(String? image, String name) async {
    if (image != null) {
      
      Size s = const Size(300, 300);

      var icon = await createCustomMarkerBitmapWithNameAndImage(image, s, name);
    
      return icon;
    } else {
      return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
    }
  }
```

Ese BitmapDescriptor es usado como sigue:

```
final endMarkerImage = await getMarkerIcon('assets/imageMap/user2.png', 'galo');

final endMarker = Marker(
  // anchor: const Offset(5.0, 0.0),
  markerId: const MarkerId('end'),
  icon: endMarkerImage,
  position: destination.points.last,
);
```

Y estoy obteniendo el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me esta quedando desfasada la imagen que deberia estar en el centro de la circunferencia, ademas, no me esta quedando en la ubicacion establecida, en este caso, en el destino final de la ruta marcada con polylines. Que puedo hacer para corregir esto?